# How to specify the QString::indexOf method not to be sensitive to the number of spaces between two words?

Tags: c++, qt, indexof, qstring

I have written a source code like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QFile File (directory + "/File");

        if(File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
         QTextStream Stream (&File);
         QString FileText;
           do
            {
      FileText = Stream.readLine();
    QString s = "start";
    QString e = "end   here";
    int start = FileText.indexOf(s, 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 
    int end = FileText.indexOf(e, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 

    if(start != -1){ // we found it

        QString y = FileText.mid(start + s.length(), (end - (start + s.length()))); 

        qDebug() << y << (start + s.length()) << (end - (start + s.length()));
    }
```

}

My problem here is, that the int end = FileText.indexOf(e, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
with `QString e = "end   here";` is just found when there are exactly three spaces between the word "end" and "here". This is problematical, because in the text I read the spaces between these two words will surely differ from time to time. Furthermore I need to write both words "end" and "here". I tried to reduce the problem to the basis and hope someone has an idea/solution.

Comment: are you just looking for the occurance of "end here" and "start" in your stream?

Comment: I am looking for them and after that extract whats between them with the ".mid() method". Surely I have to search for many more words in my stream/text, because I have to extract many more strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the number of inter-spaces to 1 using [`QString::simplified()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qstring.html#simplified) method.

Comment: You mean I should use QString::simplified on the QString FileText so that all spaces between two words are reduced to one space? Would that also assemble two lines, because that would be bad to me? On the other hand I am not sure if that would even matter xD - I'll just try it...

Comment: Hmmm, I tried it with a few methods and it did not work. Before the "do command" I typed in " FileText = FileText.simplified(); " but I again did not get the String. (?)

Comment: @Streight Before "do command"? It should be after (or in)! You have to add `FileText = FileText.simplified();` after `FileText = Stream.readLine()`.

Comment: Uuups, guess I have slept :D. Works now fine!. Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [QRegExp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html):

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QRegExp>

int main()
{
    QString text("start ABCDE1234?!-: end  here foo bar");

    // create regular expression
    QRegExp rx("start\\s+(.+)\\s+end\\s+here", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    int pos=0;

    // look for possible matches
    while ((pos=rx.indexIn(text, pos)) != -1) {
        qDebug() << rx.cap(1); // get first match in (.+)
        pos+=rx.matchedLength();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guess that would have worked fine, too, but I have done it now the other way. greetings